# Printing value from array sometimes not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

This is so strange. The first one prints nothing, while if I do a `die` with some random text attached to it, it prints the `id`. Can someone please explain?

This is working:

```
        $product_ids = ProductToOption::groupBy('product_id')->get(['product_id']);

        foreach($product_ids as $product_id) {
            die("id: ".$product_id->product_id);
            array_push($filter_array, $product_id->product_id);
        }
```

But this one isn't:

```
        $product_ids = ProductToOption::groupBy('product_id')->get(['product_id']);

        foreach($product_ids as $product_id) {
            die($product_id->product_id);
            array_push($filter_array, $product_id->product_id);
        }
```

Comment: once something `die()`'s, the next lines are not executed, *n'est-ce pas?* http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php *"die — Equivalent to exit"* - *This language construct is equivalent to [`exit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php).*

Comment: yes, but why is it printing the `id: 1` and not the just `1`? I know what die means, but in example it states exact the same, except with adding a text `id:` to it, it shows

Comment: see the answer below, that's why it's failing you.

Comment: A fix would be to wrap it in double quotes `die("$product_id->product_id");`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If value passed to **die()** is an **int**, it won't be printed but used as return code of the process executing the script - see http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php for more info.

When you concatenate the **int** with **id:** the string is passed to **die()** instead of **integer**, that's why it results in **id: 1** being printed.

---

From the manual on [`exit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php):

> If status is a string, this function prints the status just before exiting.
>
> If status is an [integer](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php), that value will be used as the exit status and not printed. Exit statuses should be in the range 0 to 254, the exit status 255 is reserved by PHP and shall not be used. The status 0 is used to terminate the program successfully.
>
> Note: PHP >= 4.2.0 does NOT print the status if it is an [integer](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php).

Comment: To add to this answer, a fix would be to wrap it in double quotes `die("$product_id->product_id");` if they want to return the integer as a string; that will work.

Comment: OK, another question.... is this also why it's not pushing the value to the array? Cause the array stays blanks, while the `foreach ` has values

Comment: @AlvinBakker I said that [here...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34179642/printing-value-from-array-sometimes-not-working#comment56105412_34179642) remember? ;-) `array_push($filter_array, $product_id->product_id);` won't happen, because of the `die()`.

Comment: I know :P but after disabling the `die()` of course. But I got it to work though. Thanx for your help guys